# Downloading Website in Python

Tags: python, html

How would I go about downloading web pages using Python in such a way that I could view them offline as well as sift through their `html` code for information?

Just like right clicking and clicking `Save-As` on any web page.

Comment: Checkout beautifulsoup

Comment: @UmangGupta I did, how would you go about it? I see alot of example s on how to get parts of the website but not the entire thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

The simples example would go something like this (note: both of these libraries you have to install first using pip `python -m pip install <library>`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup

res = requests.get('www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


print(soup.prettify())
```

The last line will print out the entire html of the website but it will also format it in a readable form just like when you look at the html by inspecting element on a website.

If you want to download the page and put it in a separate html file you can do that like this:

```
with open('example.html', 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as webSite:
    webSite.write(soup.prettify())

webSite.close()
```